# How to change font family in footnote, equations and one paragraph?

Tags: pdftex

I am using Texmaker in Linux Mint and I am currently compiling with pdfLatex.

I am using berasans font family like this:

```
\usepackage[scaled]{berasans}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}  %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

And I have 3 problems to be fixed:

1. I want to change the default (Roman I think) font family of the footnotes to berasans.
2. I also want change the default Math font family to berasans (I use the eqnarray environment).
3. At last, I want to change just two lines font family to Arial Narrow.

I've been searching for the solutions but I have not found anything that works for me.

Thanks for your time!